# Ayuda ocultando extensiones con archivo htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

chicos tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo .htaccess y deseo saber quien me puede ayudar a ordenar mi codigo:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html

<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A432000
ExpiresByType image/svg A432000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A432000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A432000
ExpiresByType image/png A432000
ExpiresByType image/ico A432000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A432000
ExpiresByType text/css A432000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A432000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A432000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A432000
</ifmodule>
```

estoy tratando de ocultar la extensiones de mis archivos implementando el siguiente codigo:

```
#RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Pero no logro hacerlo funcionar me da error 500 y otras veces no oculta la extension del archivo mostrando en el navegador los nombres de los archivos ejemplo login.php usuario.php admin.php.

Comment: Lo que buscas es que un navegador no muestra la página de directorio con los nombres de los archivos? Es eso?

Comment: Si que ejemplo una web www.miweb.com/login.php se muestre asi: www.miweb.com/login